# How to configure Appium Android with Charles Proxy?

Tags: testing, proxy, appium, charles-proxy

How do you configure Android Device while using Appium automation with Charles Proxy I need to inject map local code to bypass a feature. I get weak connection error when running Appium with Charles Proxy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know really know about Appium, but in order to get Charles capturing all your Android's http requests you need to configure a proxy server under it's WiFi configuration (Settings -> WiFi -> select your wifi connection -> Modify network config -> Manual Proxy Settings -> Host: IP of your computer hosting CharlesProxy. Port: usually 8888 (you can check it under Proxy Settings on CharlesProxy).
Obviously you will need your Android device to be in the same network your computer is connected to.

Comment: I tried that but when I run it with Appium it says no connections error.

Comment: Hey, Were u able to configure charles  proxy with appium for automation ?